# Why is the more substituted C-atom attacked in oxymercuration-demercuration?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In hydration of an alkene by oxymercuration-demercuration , for an asymetrical mercunium ion, the more substituted carbon atom is attacked by water

Why is this the case?
Since R groups are electron donating, it should make the more substituted carbon less electrophilic but the reverse is true.

Comment: That's all right. Whatever is attacked by an electrophile should be **nucleophilic**, not electrophilic.

Comment: Made a mistake in writing my question. Fixed.

Comment: The mercury just electrophilically activates the alkene (kind of like proton). The electrophilic center is the one that is better able to bear a partial positive charge.

Comment: The Mercury because of it's + charge withdraws electrons via the inductive effect. The R group stabilizes the electron deficiency on the more substituted carbon atom making it less electrophilic